# google compute engine requests from External IP of Load Balancer

Tags: networking, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have n instances behind a network load balancer with static IP. So clients are satisfied with an available instance through internet and then the load balancer. However, the instances have also applications that make external calls to an API that has limited to the whitelisted IPs. Since there is also autoscaling managing my n instances behind the LB, I don't have specific list of external IPs of the instances.

Therefore, I would like to make outgoing requests through static IP of the LB.

I have read the networking and it seems I can make routing through one of the instances and whitelist its IP. But what it is unavailable or down.

Is there a way to make outgoing requests go out to internet through LBs external IP? Or a similar solution?

Comment: Maybe route all outbound requests through a NAT gateway (preferably with some redundancy) so that all outbound requests appear to come from fixed IP(s) of the NAT? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#routing

Comment: You can achieve redundancy by using internal load balancing - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/

Comment: it seems like internel load balancer is the guy. it seems like, I have to delete external IP's from the instances. I will try that and feedback

Comment: @Dincer, did internal load balacer fit your use case? Can I ask where is the API server running. Is it on the same network as of other n instances?

Comment: Hi Kamran, I couldnot have tried this. It has been busy days. If I get it done I will share for sure.

Comment: Sadly it did not work. If I have an LB for http/s, I need to put another internal that may help. But it's too much for such a functionality for the scale of my project.